# Lograr efecto de blur en firefox

Tags: html5, css3

Estoy intentando replicar este efecto de blur de la derecha (chrome) en firefox, pero no lo logro. Que me estoy perdiendo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos son los estilos que estoy utilizando.

```css
/*
* Prefixed by https://autoprefixer.github.io
* PostCSS: v7.0.29,
* Autoprefixer: v9.7.6
* Browsers: last 4 version
*/

.form-signin-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 2%;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
    0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);

  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px) grayscale(0.3);
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px) grayscale(0.3);
}
.form-signin {
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: auto;
}

.form-signin .checkbox {
  font-weight: 400;
}
.form-signin .form-control {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.form-signin .form-control:focus {
  z-index: 2;
}

input {
  text-align: center;
}
.form-signin input[type='email'] {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.form-signin input[type='password'] {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

Y este el html:

````html
<div class="form-signin-div">
  <form class="form-signin text-center">
    <img
      class="mb-4 mt-4"
      src="assets/images/logo-light-text.png"
      alt="IMPERIUMsic logo"
    />
    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-bolder text-white bg-dark-gray">
      Iniciar sesión
    </h1>

    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Usuario</label>
    <input
      [(ngModel)]="email"
      type="email"
      name="email"
      id="inputEmail"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="Usuario"
      required=""
      autofocus=""
      autocomplete="username"
      [disabled]="loading"
    />
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Contraseña</label>
    <input
      class="mt-2"
      [(ngModel)]="password"
      type="password"
      name="password"
      id="inputPassword"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="Contrasena"
      required=""
      autocomplete="current-password"
      [disabled]="loading"
    />

    <div class="form-check">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        class="form-check-input"
        id="recordar"
        [checked]="emailGuardado()"
      />
      <label
        class="form-check-label text-white"
        for="recordar"
        (click)="recordar = !recordar"
        >Recordar correo</label
      >
    </div>

    <span class="w-100">
      <h1>
        <i
          [style.visibility]="loading ? 'visible' : 'hidden'"
          class="fas fa-sync fa-spin-fast"
        ></i>
      </h1>
    </span>

    <button
      (click)="ingresar()"
      class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
      type="submit"
    >
      Iniciar sesión
    </button>
    <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted text-center">
      © Codice Progressio {{ copyRight }}
    </p>
  </form>
</div>```
````

Comment: Borra el `-webkit` y deja únicamente el filtro. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/filter

Comment: Todos los que aparecen? O a que te refieres?

Comment: `-webkit-*`  es un prefijo de marco que utilizan navegadores como Safari y Chrome. Firefox utiliza `-moz-*`, `-ms-*` para Internet Explorer. Aunque viendo la compatibilidad, en Firefox no funciona. Revisa la sugerencia que allí mencionan: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter

Comment: Ok. Se aplica el blur, pero sobre todos los elementos que son hijos de el elemento con la clase, incluido los inputs. Parece que necesito `backdrop-filter` pero en firefox no se muestra.